# How to reuse the result of pipelined table function as an argument of another function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

inside my package spec I have declared these types :

```
type myrecord is record (
a integer,
b integer,
);
type mytable is table of myrecord
```

Previously I had done that in the package body:

```
function myfunction1 return mytable is
    ret mytable;
    SELECT *  bulk collect into ret FROM aTableOfMyDatabase;
    return ret;
end myfunction1

function myfunction2(arg mytable) return integer is
    ret integer :=0;
    SELECT COUNt(*) into ret from arg;
    return ret;
end myfunction2
```

I used this function like this

```
value integer :=myfunction2(myfunction1());
```

I works but this is not efficient because a intermedary table is stored.

THerefore I have transformed the first function like that:

```
function myfunction1 return mytable PIPELINED is
    ret myrecord;-- instead of mytable
    for c in (
         SELECT *  bulk collect into myrecord.a, myrecord.b FROM aTableOfMyDatabase
    )LOOP
         PIPE ROW(myrecord)
    end loop;

    -- NO REturn
end myfunction1
```

But i can use the function1 result with function2 because the type is different. And I don't want to create a intermediary table because the change in function1 won't be useful anymore.

HAs somebody a solution to change2 by keeping the advantage of using a pipe table function?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the example.  For example, in the initial code, neither function appears to take a parameter (function2 also has no FROM clause).  I assume that `function1` is defined to accept a collection as input, select from that input, and return a result.  How is that parameter defined (specifically, are you using `NOCOPY`)?  You could define `function1` as a user-defined aggregate function instead.  But it isn't obvious that would be more efficient or why you are concerned about the efficiency of the current solution (i.e. is there really a problem or is it theoretical).

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for your remark, I haven't written correctly. Now it's fixed

Comment: Thanks Pierre-olivier Gendraud.  I would agree with Justin Cave's comment, and just add that Pipelined Table functions cannot be directly invoked in PL/SQL, but must be invoked in SQL.  I believe in this case you cannot take advantage of pipelining, as the parameter in myfunction2 will need to be fully-formed, and any SQL statement used to partially evaluate myfunction1 would need to complete before its output could be passed to myfunction2 anyway.